# Why is it that the following code runs perfectly fine in python but givees error in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
"""The following program populates dictionary with (i,i*i) \
    for all numbers btw 1 to n for the users input"""
def intDict():
    n=int(input('Enter an integer for which you want to populate the dictionary: '))
    d=dict()
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        d[i]=i**2
    print(d)
intDict()
```

The above program runs well in python but occurs an error when runs in Jupyter. This is just one of the problems, I have done so many similar codes that run fine in python but fails in Jupyter.

I am new to coding in  general so I cant find the source of the bug, all I know is that when I put the `input()` within the function it gives error, while if I place it outside it works just as fine in Jupyter(runs great in python both ways).

```
Enter an integer for which you want to populate the dictionary: 4

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6700/1184304996.py in <module>
      7         d[i]=i**2
      8     print(d)
----> 9 intDict()

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6700/1184304996.py in intDict()
      2     for all numbers btw 1 to n for the users input"""
      3 def intDict():
----> 4     n=int(input('Enter an integer for which you want to populate the dictionary: '))
      5     d=dict()
      6     for i in range(1,n+1):

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Above is just one of the error.
I have tried restarting kernel, reopening the notebook etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you by any chance using `input` as a variable in other cells?

Comment: My bet is on `type(int)` yields `float`. Which would be kind of funny.

Comment: Yup am using  `input` in other cells. Looking at your comment I thought to open a fresh notebook and try the code in that and now it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Any reason why such is the problem?

Comment: `input` is the built-in function of that name, unless you assign something else to this name. For example, something like `input = 3.14` is a bad idea, because it will *shadow* the built-in function, as now `input('Enter an integer')` is evaluated as `3.14('Enter an integer')`, which raises the error you saw.

Comment: Thanks buddy well explained. I'll keep that in mind from next time.